# Disallow setting New or Undeclared property in an object

Tags: javascript, object, properties

Suppose I have a JavaScript object with some properties.

```
var properties = {
    x : 10,
    y : 20,
    z : 30,
};
```

Here, I declared and defined the properties `x`, `y`, and `z`. Thus I can access them using `properties.x`, `properties.y`, `properties.z` respectively.

Suppose I now try to set another property that I haven't declared.

```
properties.foo = 100;
```

It turns out this is allowed, and `properties.foo` is now defined to be `100`.

However, since I never declared `foo` in `var properties = { ... }`, I would like to make it so that when someone attempts to set `foo`, an Exception is thrown.

**Or more generally, I would like to throw an exception when someone attempts to set any property that I did not initially declare in `var properties = { ... }`.**

Is this possible?

Ideally, I should still be able to change properties that I previously set. Thus, I should still be able to do `properties.x = 40;` without any problems.

My motivate for wanting to do so is to prevent making a typo when changing existing properties. For example, I intend to set `properties.x = 40` but accidentally wrote `properties.c = 40`. This may have undesired effects and/or induces debugging headaches.

---

[Here is an example in jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/uszc2z96/2/)

```
var properties = {
    x : 10,
    y : 20,
    z : 30,
};

console.log(properties.x); // ok, logs 10
console.log(properties.y); // ok, logs 20
console.log(properties.z); // ok, logs 30

properties.foo = 100; // should not be ok, because there is no foo in properties.

properties.x = 40; // should be ok.
console.log(properties.x); // ok, logs 40

console.log(properties.foo); // logs 100, but should be undefined.
```

Comment: See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/uszc2z96/1/)

Comment: @Tushar That does address my problem. However, what if I have many properties to set? It is a bit impractical to use an if-statement to check all of them. Is this the only way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript allows u to add properties at any time. The code is doing what it should.
If you want to prevent that, you have to use the EcmaScript5 function

```
Object.freeze()
```

On your object. This makes it unchangable.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Unfortunately it makes it [impossible to change even properties that I did set.](http://jsfiddle.net/3qrt7k4y/1/). I apologize for not making this more clear in my question. Do you have any suggestions that will prevent setting of new properties while still allowing modifying old properties? Or is there no better way?

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of not adding new props is, but how about making a function that returns getters and setters for them, then call object freeze on the function?

Comment: Mainly, to prevent making a typo when changing existing properties. e.g. I want to set `properties.x = 40` but accidentally wrote `properties.c = 40`, which may have undesired effects and/or induces debugging headaches.

Comment: Okay. Personally, I think it will be more of a headache to prevent those typos than what you will gain. Maybe use some ide that do there checks?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Object.preventExtensions()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions). Existing properties can still be modified, but any attempt to add a new one will throw a `TypeError`.

```js
let properties = Object.preventExtensions({
  x : 10,
  y : 20,
  z : 30,
})

properties.x = 40 // 40
properties.c = 40 // TypeError: Cannot add property c, object is not extensible
```

Note that properties can still be deleted.

```js
delete properties.x // {y: 20, z: 30}
```